# Equivalence of semicontinuity definitions.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning

**Def 1**. A function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is **upper semicontinuous** if $\forall x\in X:\forall \{x_n\}\subseteq X: x_n \rightarrow x \ \text{implies} \ f(x)\geq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n) $.

**Def 2**. A function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is **upper  semicontinuous** if $\forall x\in X:\forall \{x_n\}\subseteq X: x_n \rightarrow x \ \text{implies} \ \forall \epsilon >0:\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n>N:f(x)> f(x_n)-\epsilon $.

To show that both definitions are equivalent I decided to show the following: 
$$\ f(x)\geq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n) \iff \forall \epsilon >0:\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n>N:f(x)> f(x_n)-\epsilon.$$

---

**My attempt**

Let $x \in X$ and let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$. Then

\begin{align}
&f(x)\geq \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{k\geq n} f(x_k))\\
\iff  &\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n>N:f(x)\geq \sup_{k\geq n} f(x_k).
\end{align}
Note that $\sup_{k\geq n} f(x_k)$ forms a decreasing sequence along $n$. Furthermore, $\forall \epsilon>0$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sup_{k\geq n} f(x_k)\geq f(x_n)>f(x_n)-\epsilon $ . Thus

\begin{align}
 &\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n>N:f(x)\geq \sup_{k\geq n} f(x_k)\\
\iff & \forall \epsilon>0:\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n>N:f(x)>f(x_n)-\epsilon.
\end{align}

**Remark**. To see the $(\Leftarrow)$ in the last equivalence above, note that as $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we have $\forall n>N:f(x)\geq f(x_n)$, which implies $f(x)\geq \sup_{k\geq N}f(x_k)$, which in turn implies $\forall n>N, f(x)\geq \sup_{k\geq n}f(x_k)$, since $\sup_{k\geq n}f(x_k)$ is decreasing in $n$.

Do you agree with that?

Thanks!